# Android keyboard hiding some input boxes and cant scroll

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard, phonegap-build

Phonegap - When I select an input box on my register form, it loads the keyboard which then hides some of the form. Usually, with an app, you can just scroll up and down but I can't... here's my config. xml.. and I've tried adding these two lines in but not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

If this IS the answer, wherebouts should I be placing these lines? I tried adding them after the 3rd Preference tag but no joy.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>
<platform name="wp8">
    <icon height="99" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
    <icon height="159" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />
    <splash height="1280" platform="wp8" src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" width="768" />
</platform>
<platform name="windows">
    <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
    <icon height="30" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
    <icon height="50" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
    <splash height="300" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
    <icon height="120" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
    <icon height="106" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
    <icon height="70" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
    <icon height="71" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
    <icon height="170" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
    <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
    <icon height="310" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
    <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
    <splash height="1920" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
</platform>
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Comment: I would think this is a HTML / CSS issue specifically.  Can you pad the page a bit on the bottom? Sounds like you just can't scroll.

Comment: Thank you, just added a min-height to the main div and worked fine. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, feel embarrassed now ha.